# How to restore (shortcut icon) for Firefox in Windows 8.1 system x64

Tags: firefox, windows-8.1, desktop-icons

Firefox icon shows on Start Menu and Taskbar but a generic icon shows on Desktop.  From the Start Menu a right click does not give options of Send To Desktop or any other place.  Also in file location there is a generic icon and not the Firefox icon.  What is the problem and how to restore or correct it?

Comment: Please provide an imgur screenshot of what you are talking about.

Comment: You may restore/rebuild icon cache in windows. Try to delete or pin and unpin the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to fix my taskbar icon:
Right click on the generic icon that is supposed to be Firefox
Right click on the Firefox icon that shows up in the list
You should have the "Run as administrator" option available now - click on that.
FF will open, and it should also fix your icon.
In your case, you should be able to just right click the desktop icon and click Run as Administrator.